# mysql procedure error does not run

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am quite new to `stored procedures` in MySQL but by the power of google and documentation i have finally finished (sort of) my first procedure.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `modules`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE team_id INT;
  DECLARE phase_id INT;
  DECLARE module_id INT;
  DECLARE user_id INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT P.team_id,P.id,M.id,UHT.user_id FROM phase P INNER JOIN module M ON P.Module_id = M.id JOIN user_has_team UHT ON UHT.team_id = P.team_id WHERE M.module_type = 7 or M.module_type = 8 AND P.end <= NOW();  
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO team_id, phase_id,module_id, user_id;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
      INSERT INTO offline_score VALUES (null,team_id,phase_id,module_id,1,NOW(),1);
  END LOOP;
END
```

Now i wanted to test my creation and did the following

```
CALL modules
```

However after checking my `offline_score` table i could see that nothing was inserted.

Can anyone see if there is a problem with my code or know how i am able to debug for i can find the error?

After the call i get the following output:

```
1   14:36:24    CALL modules    0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1329 No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? If not did you try executing the query manually that you have inside the procedure to see if it returns some data. Also `end` is a reserved keyword that you are using in the query make sure to use backtick for it.

Comment: i get the following output:

3 12:46:59 CALL modules 30 row(s) returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your data looks like but this query might be an issue:

```
SELECT P.team_id,P.id,M.id,UHT.user_id FROM phase P 
     INNER JOIN module M ON P.Module_id = M.id 
     JOIN user_has_team UHT ON UHT.team_id = P.team_id 
   WHERE M.module_type = 7 or M.module_type = 8 AND P.end <= NOW();
```

Try changing the `where` to

```
WHERE M.module_type = 7 or ( M.module_type = 8 AND P.end <= NOW());
```

or

```
WHERE ( M.module_type = 7 or M.module_type = 8)  AND P.end <= NOW();
```

depending on your needs